# What is the cardinality of the set of all groups (up to isomorphism) of countable order?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Apologies if this is a known result, I have looked around and could not find it.

There is a pretty vast literature on the number of groups up to isomorphism of order $n$, for any natural number $n$. [This paper](https://web.math.ku.dk/%7Eolsson/manus/three-group-numbers.pdf) for instance classifies for which $n$ are there are one, two, or three groups of order $n$. However, I haven't been able to find any results, not even partial, on the cardinality of the number of groups up to isomorphism of order $|\mathbb N|$. Is this known, and if not are there partial results on it? I suspected that the number of abelian groups up to isomorphism would be known (as it is a well-known result for finite groups) but I cannot find the result, if it is published.

Comment: What is meant with a "group of countable order" ?

Comment: group on a number of elements of cardinality equal to the natural numbers. Sorry if my terminology is a bit sloppy.

Comment: There are lots of them.  $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, etc.

Comment: There are lots of countable groups, even with stronger constraints. For example for any prime $p$ there are continuum of $p$-groups generated by two elements only. This is shown by Olshansky I think.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but this begs the question of whether this is a well-defined set. The 'set of all groups' is not well-defined, for example. I'm sure this is known, so I wonder if a set theorist can chime in on this?

Comment: @jpmacmanus for any cardinality, there is a set $X$ of groups of this cardinality s.t. any group of this cardinality is isomorphic to one of groups in $X$, and this set has cardinality at most $|X|^{|X|^2}$ (which, I think, is $2^{|X|}$ assuming choice, if $X$ is infinite).

Comment: (sorry, in the comment above it should be "$X$ has a cardinality of at most $|Y|^{|Y|^2}$", where $Y$ is target cardinality of group)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is at most continuum such groups: every group can be defined by function $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, and there are only continuum such functions.

There is also at least continuum such groups: for every subset of primes $X$, group $\mathbb Z \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{x \in X} \mathbb Z_x$ is countable, and groups for different $X$ are non-isomorphic: if two sets $X_1$ and $X_2$ differ in prime $p$, then one of corresponding groups includes element of order $p$, and other doesn't.

Comment: You don't need the $\mathbb{Z}$ summand: just take *infinite* subsets of primes; there's already a continuum of them.

Comment: We have a choice here: add $\mathbb Z$ as a summand, or talk about infintie subsets. The former is shorter to write so I chose it.